# PHP - Generate file on the fly for android devices

Tags: php, android, header, on-the-fly

I have read some answers here but i cannot seem to make my php script to work.
I generate a text or csv file (it depends what the user has chosen) from a form that it is submitted back to the same page.
The script works fine on Chrome, IE, Mozilla on my desktop but when i try on the stock browser on Android i get an attachment.html file that has the source of my script.
If i try with NEXT browser, i get a file with the proper filename but again inside is the source of my script.

I have read the following link but i cannot make it work
http://www.digiblog.de/2011/04/android-and-the-download-file-headers/

My http headers are the following

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($FileName) . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($FileName));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Connection: close");
print $Content;
exit();
```

-----Update 1----

I wrote the following code to test things out

```
<?php
$get = $_GET['get'];
if ($get == 1) {
$content = 'This is a line of text!';
$filename = 'superfile';
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . ".TXT\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Connection: close");
echo $content;
exit;

}
echo '<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="index.php"
    <label>Get</label>
    <input type="text" name="get"/>
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

When i send the form with get method everything works, when i use post i get the html source that you see, same as the problem that i have with my original script.

-----Update 2-----

Okkkkk, now some more info, i think it is related to an Android bug, please check the following link

http://roscopeco.com/2013/04/android-and-the-form-post-download-problem/

Waiting for suggestions to work around this issue, i need method to me post because i pass too many varialbes and i don't want to have on big ugly url on the address bar.

Comment: You are getting served the actual PHP code if you browse the page from a mobile?

Comment: Tried without a parenthesis and didn't work. The form uses POST method and it is submitted back to the same page. The url is something like this http://localhost/myapp/index.php?page=firstpage. No, i see properly the form, i submit it, get to accept the download but the file is not the one i get from my desktop browsers.

Comment: I tried with several browsers, Chrome, Mozilla, Opera work fine. With stock android browser, next browser and dolpin i get a file with the source of the page (not the source of my script).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn't want to experiment too much so i get the user-agent and i change my post form to a get. Not a great fix but the job is done.